# how to handle when there's no body

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, combine

Usually, in delete request, the response code is `204 (no content)`

How'd you handle such using Combine, when there's no body to json decode.

```
func deleteById(_ id: Int) -> AnyPublisher<Void, Error> {
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://domain/products/\(id)")!)
    request.httpMethod = "DELETE"

    return session.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
            .map { (data, response) -> AnyPublisher<Void, Error> in
                Just(())
                        .setFailureType(to: Error.self)
                        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

---

**Attempt**

```
func deleteById(_ id: Int) -> AnyPublisher<Void, Error> {
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://domain/products/\(id)")!)
    request.httpMethod = "DELETE"

    return session.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
            .map { _ in return } // return nothing
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`URLSession.dataTaskPublisher` gives you a publisher with the `Failure` type of `URLError`. The return type of your method says the return value should have an `Failure` type of just `Error`.

Note that `flatMap` can only change the `Failure` type to `Never` (a bit like `setFailureType`). It can't change it to another `Error` type. `mapError` is what changes the failure type.

```
return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
    .map { _ in () } // '()' is a value of Void
    .mapError { $0 as Error }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Other things to consider:

- just returning `AnyPublisher<Void, URLError>`
- use `ignoreOutput()` instead of `map` to return a `AnyPublisher<Never, URLError>`. This is a publisher that does not publish any value, only completes.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going with the considerations and will ask again in any questions to handle `URLError` types

Comment: i'm trying to consume this `Never` producuer, and when attempting in completion block, `.finished`, it says Type 'Never' has no member 'finished', and of course `receiveValue` will never be executed because of the no-value.

Comment: I was depending on `.finished`, so how would I know if producer completes.

Comment: @Source Please see the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/ignoreoutput/ignoreoutput()) for an example of how to use this.

Comment: It's compiling now, Thanks for your help. Just fine-tuning. I have to check for errors too `.failure` case, since it's a network call.

Comment: see my consumer please, have some glitch because of context switching.

Comment: @Source If you have a new problem, please post a new question and include a [mcve]. Describe what the problem is, the error message you got, etc. Be sure to look for duplicates too.

Comment: 1. `Instance method 'receive(subscriber:)' requires that 'DispatchQueue' conform to 'Subscriber'`
2. `Value of tuple type '()' has no member 'sink'`

Comment: @Source Seems like you wanted to call `receive(on:)` instead of `receive(subscriber:)`?